# DataTable 1.10.10 how to get sorted column name and direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Using DataTable version 1.10.10 can't seems to get column name and order direction. I was able to get a page number like this:

```
var pageNumber = table.page.info().page + 1;
```

Need similar thing for getting sorted column name and order direction.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

Use [`order()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/order%28%29) API method to get the ordering applied to the table.

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

var order = table.order();
alert( 'Table is ordered by column: ' + order[0][0] + ', direction:' + order[0][1]);

var title = table.column(order[0][0]).header();
alert( 'Ordering column title: ' + $(title).html() );
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jemw8oty/) for code and demonstration.