# Get Sorting details in datatables.net

Tags: .net-core, datatables

I am using Datatables.net in my code and I have a scenario where I need to show in a label the sort direction and the column name I have applied Sorting.

Eg : If I have applies ascending sorting in Column Name I need to show in a label "Ascending Name".

I have tried multiple methods but not able to get the values.

Any help on this is very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: "_I have tried multiple methods_" - You can show us what you have tried, and what happened when you tried it. Ideally, do this with a [mre].

Comment: But first of all, have you read the documentation for the [`order()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/order()) API function. I believe that should do exactly what you want ("Get the current ordering of the table"). If that does not work, see my first comment.

Comment: Actually - even better: [DataTable 1.10.10 how to get sorted column name and direction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34730834/12567365)